# How to return columns and counts in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count

This is the question I am trying to solve. Also what I got so far, only problem is that only displays the mem_num and counts, I need to display the member's first and last name, which are in 2 different columns. How do I display the name next to the count?

> Create a query that returned the number of rentals for each members. 
>           The result should match the following data 
>           You will need to join the Membership and Rentals tables and count the number of records. 
>           Name the number of records as “Number of Times Rented”):

```
select m.mem_num, count(*) as "Number of Times Rented"
from membership m, rental r
where m.mem_num = r.mem_num 
group by m.mem_num;
```

Comment: Why can't you just do something like `select m.mem_num,  m.firstname, m.lastname, count(*) as "Number of Times Rented"
    from membership m, rental r
    where m.mem_num = r.mem_num 
    group by m.mem_num,  m.firstname, m.lastname ;`  (Also: Please always tag the database engine you are using, e.g. sql server, or oracle. sql is for the language).

Comment: first and last names are in membership

Comment: Just add the additional columns to the SELECT list and also the GROUP BY list

Comment: Oh, and since you are a beginner, please cease using that method of joining tables as it is frowned upon. Much better to use `from membership m inner join rental r
    on m.mem_num = r.mem_num`. Plenty of articles/blogs explaining why.

Comment: that worked! thanks nathan!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the proper, explicit, and **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

The query that you want is probably:

```
select m.mem_num, m.first_name, m.last_name,
       count(*) as "Number of Times Rented"
from membership m join
     rental r
     on m.mem_num = r.mem_num 
group bym.mem_num, m.first_name, m.last_name;
```